# ReactJs: How to pass data from one component to another?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, components, react-typescript

If two or more cards from a component are selected how to pass data to a button component?

I have a landing page that holds two components; Template list and a button.

```
<TemplateList templates={templates} />

                <MenuButton style={actionButton} onClick={onOnboardingComplete}>
                    Select at least 2 options
                </MenuButton>
```

The TemplateList brings in an array of information for my Template and creates Template Cards with it. I am then able to select my cards and unselect them.

My Button when pressed just takes me to the next step of the onboarding.

I would like to know how I should approach linking these two components. My button now is gray and would like this to happen:

**1. Button is gray and user cant go on to next step, until selecting two or more cards.**

**2. When two or more cards are selected, button turn blue and they are able to press the button to continue.**

This is my Template List:

```
export type Template = {
    title: string;
    description: string;
    imgURL: string;
    id?: number;
};

type Props = {
    templates: Template[];
};

const TemplateList = ({ templates }: Props) => {
    return (
        <div className={styles.scrollContainer}>
            {templates.map((item) => (
                <TemplateCard
                    title={item.title}
                    description={item.description}
                    img={item.imgURL}
                    classNameToAdd={styles.cardContainer}
                    key={item.id}
                />
            ))}
        </div>
    );
};

export default TemplateList;
```

And this my Template Card:

```
type Props = {
    title: string;
    description: string;
    img: string;
    classNameToAdd?: string;
    classNameOnSelected?: string;
};

const TemplateCard = ({ title, description, img, classNameToAdd, classNameOnSelected }: Props) => {
    const { aspectRatio, vmin } = useWindowResponsiveValues();
    let className = `${styles.card} ${classNameToAdd}`;

    const [selected, setSelected] = useState(false);

    const handleClick = () => {
        setSelected(!selected);
    };

    if (selected) {
        className += `${styles.card} ${classNameToAdd} ${classNameOnSelected}`;
    }
    return (
        <div style={card} className={className} onClick={handleClick}>
            <img style={imageSize} src={img}></img>
            <div style={cardTitle}>
                {title}
                {selected ? <BlueCheckIcon style={blueCheck} className={styles.blueCheck} /> : null}
            </div>
            <div style={descriptionCard}>{description}</div>
        </div>
    );
};

TemplateCard.defaultProps = {
    classNameOnSelected: styles.selected,
};

export default TemplateCard;
```

This is how it looks like now.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least 3 ways to implement your requirement:

**OPTION 1**

1. Put Button component inside the `<TemplateList>` component
2. Add one `useState` tied to `<TemplateList>` component to hold the number of
   selected cards
3. Add two new props `onSelectCard` and `onDeselectCard` to `<TemplateCard>` to increment/decrement newly created state by `1` for each selected/deselected item
4. Implement callback functions inside `<TemplateList` component (code below)
5. Call `onSelectCard` inside `<TemplateCard>` when needed (code below)

**TemplateList** Component

```js
const TemplateList = ({ templates }: Props) => {
  const [noOfSelectedCards, setNoOfSelectedCards] = useState(0);

  handleSelect = () => setNoOfSelectedCards(noOfSelectedCards + 1);
  handleDeselect = () => setNoOfSelectedCards(noOfSelectedCards - 1);

  return (
    <div classNae="template-list-container">
      <div className={styles.scrollContainer}>
        {templates.map((item) => (
          <TemplateCard
            title={item.title}
            description={item.description}
            img={item.imgURL}
            classNameToAdd={styles.cardContainer}
            key={item.id}
            onSelectCard={handleSelect}
            onDeselectCard={handleDeselect}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
      <MenuButton style={actionButton} onClick={onOnboardingComplete} className={noOfSelectedCards === 2 ? 'active' : ''}>
        Select at least 2 options
      </MenuButton>
    </div>
  );
};
```

**TemplateCard** Component

```js
const TemplateCard = ({ ..., onSelectCard, onDeselectCard }: Props) => {
  ...

  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => {
    if(selected) {
      onDeselectCard();
    } else {
      onSelectCard();
    }
    
    setSelected(!selected);
  };

  ...
};
```

Now, you'll have the current number of selected cards in your state `noOfSelectedCards` (`<TemplateList>` component) so you can conditionally render whatever `className` you want for your button or do something else with it.

**OPTION 2**

Using [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) to share state between components

It's okay to use React Context for such cases, but if your  requirements contains other similar cases for handling/sharing states between components across the app, I suggest you take a look at the 3rd option.

**OPTION 3**

Using State Management like [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) to handle global/shared states between components.

This is probably the best option for projects where sharing states across the app is quite common and important. You'll need some time to understand concepts around Redux, but after you do that I assure  you that you'll enjoy working with it.

Comment: Great! I have decided to use Option 1:
1. I Added the button inside my TemplateList component.
2. Added the onSelectCard prop on Template List. 
3. Created a className that if true shows a button of one color, and false the other color. 

The only thing I couldnt grasp yet is how to add this inside my TemplatesCard component, so that the onSelectCard prop in TemplatesList gets the number in order for me to create a if statement so that I can connect that number to my buttons actions.

Comment: I have updated my answer to give  you more specific code to resolve your problem. I hope it helps. If you manage to get this to work approve the answer, if not, let me know where you are stuck at.